Need solution to fix chakra-ui config issues given that all references of obsolete versions are rendered and inaccessible in India (foreign nation)
This is in continuation for the quest towards determining accuracy of this video, where I am stuck at the video time, involving extendTheme.  Please note that this is a chakra-ui 1.x or 2.x feature all of the branches or issues have been removed from Google Search, thanks to stereotyping, user profiling, just to avoid high treason!!!.
My package.json is as follows:
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite --host --port 5173",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "preview": "vite preview"   },   "dependencies": {
    "@chakra-ui/react": "^3.2.1",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.13.5",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.13.5",
    "framer-motion": "^11.12.0",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1"   },

My App.tsx is as follows:
import './App.css'

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      hi
    </>
  )
}

export default App


My main.tsx is as follows:
import { StrictMode } from 'react';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App.jsx';
import './index.css';
import { ChakraProvider } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { extendTheme } from "@chakra-ui/react";

const config = {
    initialColorMode: "light",
    useSystemColorMode: false, 
};

const theme = extendTheme( {config} );

createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <StrictMode>
    <ChakraProvider theme={theme}>
      <App />
    </ChakraProvider>
  </StrictMode>,
)


As you see from the video, extendTheme is introduced as a workaround over another error.  But face this issue now:

Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/node_modules/.vite/deps/@chakra-ui_react.js?> v=c2633999' does not provide an export named 'extendTheme' (at main.jsx:6:10)


Please note I only have Cyberghost as I am more closer to the enemy Russia than to NordVPN clients.  I don't want to use it to find answers that will override the stereotyping that Google has.  As an IM, I would prefer playing chess with Putin in the Guam from time to time!!!
I know I have to pull the v2.1.x or v1 of chakra, but can't do it.  For the sake of time at my disposal, please do help.
